# Sending message to DirectChannel throws "no subscribers" exception when using SpringIntegrationTest

Tags: spring-integration, spring-test, spring-integration-dsl

I'm writing a test class for testing my Spring Integration. I set a direct channel and inbound `IntegrationFlow` from that channel as follows:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class MqttIntegrationConfig {
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mqttChannelAdapter")
    fun mqttChannelAdapter(): MessageProducerSupport {
        val adapter = MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(...)
        // ... other setup omitted for brevity

        // ** make a DirectChannel and pipe it to mqtt adapter **
        val outputChannel = MessageChannels.direct().get()
        adapter.outputChannel = outputChannel

        return adapter
    }

    @Bean
    fun mqttInbound(): IntegrationFlow {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttChannelAdapter())
            .handle<String> { payload, headers ->
                logger.info("payload=$payload, headers=$headers")
                payload
            }
            .channel(mqttOutboundChannel())
            .get()
    }

    // other setups are omitted for brevity

}
```

To test it, I used `@SpringIntegrationTest` and its `noAutoStartup` to make it don't connect to actual MQTT.

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@DirtiesContext
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = ["mqttChannelAdapter"])
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [MqttIntegrationConfig::class, MyTestConfig::class])
class MyIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mqttChannelAdapter")
    private lateinit var mqttChannelAdapter: MessageProducerSupport

    @Test
    fun mytest() {
        mqttChannelAdapter.outputChannel?.send(GenericMessage(1))
    }
}
```

When I run `myTest` method it throws `MessageDispatchingException` as follows:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=1, headers={id=be5128f8-5869-0f9d-2cbb-ddaf4dafbc8e, timestamp=1688747038419}]
```

But when I changed the direct channel which was set as output channel of message adapter to a queue channel, it works.

```kotlin
val outputChannel = MessageChannels.queue().get()
adapter.outputChannel = outputChannel
```

I know it takes time to make integration channel be ready(?) and for real production usage, the message wouldn't come in before the integration flow ready, so `DirectChannel` would work.

To make this test work, is there a way to ensure that test method waits until all channel is ready so my `DirectChannel` has subscribers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as described - no any problems.

I don't know what is going on since it looks like you use some old Spring Integration version, so our difference in environment might be a case.

Another guess is missed `@EnableIntegration` on one your configuration class.

As a bonus: we have a dedicated Kotlin DSL for Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kotlin-dsl.html#kotlin-dsl

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Maybe my old version can be a problem, but I tried it again with spring 3 and spring integration 6, and got the same error. I uploaded my test project at [here](https://github.com/drunkhacker/so76638853v5/blob/main/src/test/kotlin/dev/jayhan/so76638853v5/MyIntegrationTest.kt#L53) to show the environment and setups I used. I use Spring boot 2.7.13 and Spring Integration 5.5.18

Comment: After some fixes around, I got the working code. The problem was I omitted the `@EnableIntegration` as @ArtemBilan mentioned.